# Rails 5.0.1, can't get Bootstrap 4 working properly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've just created a brand new Rails app (5.0.1). In this Rails app I want to use `Bootstrap 4`. I have done it before and it is usually straight forward, but this time I'm having some issues. Some styling are off / overridden  for some reason. I haven't added any custom styling myself yet beside installing:

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
```

See the image below for what I mean:

[image]

The button text should be white as default but when I inspect the element I can see that it is not working.

Beside adding `gem 'bootstrap'` to my gemfile I've also done the following:

`application.scss`

```
@import "bootstrap/variables.scss"; // I haven't tweaked any of the  variables yet.
@import "bootstrap";
```

And `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap
```

I'm using `Rails 5.0.1` and [bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem).

Any ideas on why it isn't working?

Comment: any `scaffolds.scss` on your apps? if yes I think you need to delete it.

Comment: No, not that I can see.

Comment: I see `color: inherit;` I think that style overwrite color style of link.

Comment: Ah, yes. The seems to be the case!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have more than one version of bootstrap working, maybe bootstrap 3 is overriding bootstrap 4.

If you are working with some bootstrap template, check if bootstrap is on its dependencies folder and choose if you want to delete that or the gem.

Other thing that could be the problem: Only use imports and not include in your application.scss

other thing: you have a rule for links that seems to be overriding the text color from white to black, add an '!important'  to override it